# ZKTECO SDK in java failed to init

Tags: java, sdk, time-and-attendance, zkteco

Tried official SDK on ZKTeco in java but every time its unable or failed to initialize return -1 Failed to initialize the algorithm library .

```
int ret = FingerprintSensorErrorCode.ZKFP_ERR_OK;
                //Initialize
                cbRegTemp = 0;
                bRegister = false;
                bIdentify = true;
                iFid = 1;
                enroll_idx = 0;
                
                if (FingerprintSensorErrorCode.ZKFP_ERR_OK != FingerprintSensorEx.Init())
                {
                    textArea.setText("Init failed!\n");
                    return;
                }
```

[SDK Link](https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory/46.html) also documentation included.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, I'm also experiencing the same issue with the C# SDK.

Comment: Not Yet as per my research there are some issues in zkteco devices.